# Adding button click event in datagridtemplatecolumn in user control from mainwindow programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, user-controls, datagridtemplatecolumn

I have a **MainWindow**. It has a stackpanel **myStack** and some other things.
In stackPanel, there is a usercontrol (**TaskGrid(_TG)**) added programmatically.
In this UserControl, there is a DataGrid(dgEmployee), which have 4 template columns. the last column contains a button.

I am trying to assign the button click event from the mainwindow constructor and handle the event here.

Here are the codes:

in **MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Grid Grid.Row="2">
    <StackPanel Name="myStack"/>
</Grid>
```

in **MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _TG = new TaskGrid();
    _TD = new _1.TaskDetails();
    _TM = new _1.TaskMaster();
    myStack.Children.Add(_TG);
    _AUC = ActiveUserControl.Grid;

    foreach (object child in myStack.Children)
    {
        string childname = "";
        if (child is FrameworkElement)
        {
            childname = (child as FrameworkElement).Name;
            if (childname == "TaskGrid")
            {
                Grid dg = ((Grid)((UserControl)child).Content);
                foreach (var item in dg.Children)
                {
                    DataGridColumn b = ((DataGrid)item).Columns[3] as DataGridColumn;

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in **TaskGrid.xaml**, the only template column is given here

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="30">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <ItemContainerTemplate>
            <Button Name="btnMaster"  Background="Transparent">
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Image Source="ArrowRight.png"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
            </Button>
        </ItemContainerTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I have to assign the click event like

```
button.click += new RoutedEvent(button_click);
```

And later use `button_click` event in the MainWindow.xaml.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait until the `UserControl` has been loaded. You could then get a reference to the `DataGrid` using the following helper method that searches for an element of a specific type recursively in the visual tree.

```
private static T GetChildOfType<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (depObj == null)
        return null;

    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);

        var result = (child as T) ?? GetChildOfType<T>(child);
        if (result != null) return result;
    }
    return null;
}
```

The same way you can get a reference to a specific cell:

```
public static DataGridCell GetCell(DataGrid dataGrid, DataGridRow rowContainer, int column)
{
    if (rowContainer != null)
    {
        System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DataGridCellsPresenter presenter =
            GetChildOfType<System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DataGridCellsPresenter>(rowContainer);
        if (presenter != null)
            return presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column) as DataGridCell;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Please refer to the following blog post for more information about this: https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/11/08/how-to-programmatically-select-and-focus-a-row-or-cell-in-a-datagrid-in-wpf/

Below is a full example for you. Note that the `DataGrid` may contain several rows and some of the rows may have been virtualized away. You will find more information about this on the link above.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _TG = new TaskGrid();
    _TD = new _1.TaskDetails();
    _TM = new _1.TaskMaster();
    myStack.Children.Add(_TG);
    _AUC = ActiveUserControl.Grid;

    _TG.Loaded += (s, e) =>
    {
        DataGrid dataGrid = GetChildOfType<DataGrid>(_TG);
        if (dataGrid != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in dataGrid.Items)
            {
                DataGridRow dgr = dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as DataGridRow;
                if (dgr != null)
                {
                    DataGridCell cell = GetCell(dataGrid, dgr, 3); //<-- column index
                    if (cell != null)
                    {
                        Button button = GetChildOfType<Button>(cell);
                        if (button != null)
                        {
                            button.Click += new RoutedEvent(button_click);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Later I caught the main window instance as parent from the usercontrol. So the way I was trying to handle the button click event in grid from main window, become unnecessary. So I could not test your code. But it seems to be right logically, so I put it as a right answer. Thanks for your help.